# Using a neural network for learning a Motion Graph?

Tags: neural-networks

In a recent paper about progress in computer animation a so called motion graph is used to describe the transition between keyframes of facial animation. [Easy Generation of Facial Animation Using Motion Graphs, 2018](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/cgf.13218) As far as i understand from the paper, they used a motion capture device to record faces of real people and extract keyframes. Then a transition matrix was created to ensure that a walk from keyframe #10 to #24 is possible but a transition from keyframe #22 to #99 is forbidden.

The idea itself sounds reasonable good, because now a solver can search in the motion graph to bring the system from a laughing face to a bored face without interruption or unnatural in-between-keyframes. But wouldn't it be great if the transition matrix can be stored inside a neural network? As far as i understand the backpropagation algorithm , the neural network can learn input-output relations. So the neural network has to learn the transition probability between two keyframes. And a second neural network can then produce the motion plan which is also be trained by a large corpus. Is that idea possible or is it the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... the neural network has to learn the transition probability between two keyframes. And a second neural network can then produce the motion plan which is also be trained by a large corpus. Is that idea possible or is it the wrong direction?

That would be trivial.

More difficult, but not hard, would be to take a 14 hour video of someone and create a new video with them saying something they have never said previously. Here is a demonstration, from the BBC YouTube channel, titled: "[Fake Obama created using AI video tool - BBC News](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmUC4m6w1wo)".

The University of Washington demonstrates, **using a variety of clips and** ***only*** **audio from an impersonator**, that [they can create realistic videos of the former president saying anything they want](https://www.washington.edu/news/2017/07/11/lip-syncing-obama-new-tools-turn-audio-clips-into-realistic-video/).

It's possible to sketch out an idea and let AI create a finished product of excellent quality.

The YouTube channel ACMSIGGRAPH has a video titled: "[Technical Papers Preview: SIGGRAPH 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t952yS8tcg8)", which is discussed on the webpage: "[Could These Be The Next High-Tech Tools That Animators Use Daily?](https://www.cartoonbrew.com/tools/could-these-be-the-next-high-tech-tools-that-animators-use-daily-158630.html)".

What you have asked about was possible long ago and not particularly difficult to do.